# Bind function (delegate) arguments

Tags: c#, lambda, callback, delegates, bind

I'm trying to achieve the following without using lambda function:

```
Func<bool> test = () => RunSomething("test");  <-- This work fine but creates lambda
Func<bool> test = bind(RunSomething, "test"); <-- Bind "test" to RunSomething
```

In other words I'm want to know if it is possible to somehow bind Function and arguments.
It is possible in C++ using std::bind, but is it possible in C# ?

Comment: What's wrong w/ lambdas?

Comment: @PhilipPittle nothing, but I am missing boost::bind aka std::bind from C++ also. It is just another "use case" (imho).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html

Comment: one more thought on that: with bind, you bind the value, with lambda you assign the variable, if the variable's value changes in the outer scope, it will also change in the (lambda) inner scope, so there is a huge difference

Answer (score 8):

Well it's easy to *build* such a method, but that would use a lambda expression for the implementation:

```
public Func<TResult> Bind<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func, T arg)
{
    return () => func(arg);
}
```

And likewise some overloads for functions with more arguments:

```
public Func<T2, TResult> Bind<T1, T2, TResult>
    (Func<T1, T2, TResult> func, T1 arg)
{
    return t2 => func(arg, t2);
}

public Func<T2, TResult> Bind<T1, T2, T3, TResult>
    (Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> func, T1 arg)
{
    return (t2, t3) => func(arg, t2, t3);
}
```

Keep going as far as you want - possibly even adding methods to bind more than one argument in a call.

You *can* do all this without a lambda expression, but it would just be more work. For example:

```
public Func<TResult> Bind<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func, T arg)
{
    return new Binder<T, TResult>(func, arg).Apply;
}

private sealed class Binder<T, TResult>
{
    private readonly T arg;
    private readonly Func<T, TResult> func;

    internal Binder(Func<T, TResult> func, T arg)
    {
        this.func = func;
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public TResult Apply()
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
}
```

That's basically what the compiler would do for you automatically with a lambda expression, so why do it yourself?

Comment: And, to be honest, what would be the point (in this particular case)?

Comment: @J.Steen: I think there can be cases where the intention is clearer if you express it as an explicit bind call - but it's not a big difference.

Comment: The point is I want to know how Type.InvokeMember binds object[] args to function.

Comment: @JobNick: Presumably it looks at the signature and does it all with reflection. I fail to see how the question you asked has *anything* to do with `Type.InvokeMember` though - it's a different kind of "bind", really, in that it's invoking the method immediately, rather than performing partial function application.

Comment: @JobNick That was *so* not clear from your question. =)

Comment: A note on "What's wrong w/ lambdas?", as commented on the question, it appears that the value in the lambda is actually bound by reference. I have a loop adding several callbacks and the functions were always called with the final value, not the value at the time of the call.
This pattern ensures that the *value* is bound.