# Func<T1, TResult> TResult wrapped into Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

```
public Task<Tresult> WrapIntoTask<Tresult>(Func<Tresult> function) 
where Tresult : class
{
    return Task.Run(function);
}
public Task<Tresult> WrapIntoTask<T, Tresult>(Func<T, Tresult> function) 
where Tresult : class where T : class
{
     return Task.Run(function); // Cannot pass in Func<T1, Tresult>
}
```

First method meets the requirements and works fine, while second method does not allow compile.

**How to pass in actual `T` value into `Task`?**

Comment: Well, you've said that the delegate is a function taking a single parameter, of type `T`, what do you intend to pass as a value to that parameter? You could do `Task.Run(new Func<TResult>(() => function(someValue)))`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That returns `Task<Func<T1,Tresult>>`, not `Task<Tresult>` as it does in the first `Task` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to pass a delegate that takes no additional parameters to `Task.Run`, you need to wrap a parameter-taking delegate into a no-argument delegate by passing a parameter of type `T`.

```
return Task.Run(() => function(default(T)));
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^
//                            Replace this
```

Of course you need the instance of type `T` to be passed to `function` in place of `default(T)`. For example, you could pass `T` along with `function`, like this:

```
public Task<Tresult> WrapIntoTask<T, Tresult>(Func<T, Tresult> function, T arg) 
where Tresult : class where T : class
{
     return Task.Run(() => function(arg));
}
```

Comment: Ok. Second approach is what I was looking for. Anyway isn't there more elegant way? I mean, my longest method would have 5 params.

Comment: @Carl Unfortunately, C# has no built-in capabilities for partial function invocation, so you need to write overloads for each set of parameters. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27251027/335858) for a discussion of a related topic.